# Calling external API using springboot RestTemplate, throwing exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to consume a REST API using Springboot Resttemplate. This is working fine when testing on local system and I can consume the data. But when I have deployed the same service on Heroku, It is throwing below exception. I am unable to figure out what is the issue with it. I am new to Heroku Environment. Please help if I am missing anything

Code :

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                .build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }

public void checkAvailability(VaccineRequest vaccineRequest) {
        String url = findByPinUrl.replace("#pin#", vaccineRequest.getPinCode()).replace("#date#", vaccineRequest.getDate());

        log.info("API-SETU-URL - {}", url);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add("user-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);

        ResponseEntity<Response> responseObj = null;

        try {
            responseObj = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Response.class);
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            log.info("Exception while invoking apisetu url : {}", e);
        }


        log.info("Response : {}", responseObj);
}
```

Stack trace :

```
2021-05-05T12:33:27.288037+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-05-05 12:33:27.285  INFO 4 --- [io-10945-exec-3] c.c.vaccine.controller.PrimeController   : incoming data - VaccineRequest(name=Test, emailId=test@ail.com, mobileNo=9123456789, pinCode=321605, date=06-05-2021)
2021-05-05T12:33:27.299811+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-05-05 12:33:27.299  INFO 4 --- [io-10945-exec-3] c.c.vaccine.service.VaccineCheckerImpl   : API-SETU-URL - **https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByPin?pincode=321605&date=06-05-2021**
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082346+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-05-05 12:33:29.081  INFO 4 --- [io-10945-exec-3] c.c.vaccine.service.VaccineCheckerImpl   : Exception while invoking apisetu url : {}
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082365+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082370+00:00 app[web.1]: **org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082371+00:00 app[web.1]: <HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">**
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082372+00:00 app[web.1]: <TITLE>ERROR... (919 bytes)]
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082372+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082373+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:186) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082373+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082374+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082377+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082377+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082378+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082378+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
2021-05-05T12:33:29.082379+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.covid19.vaccine.service.VaccineCheckerImpl.checkAvailability(VaccineCheckerImpl.java:70)
```

Comment: Well? What part of 403 Forbidden do you not understand?

Comment: First of all, Thank you for commenting. I want to understand that same code is working while running on local but after deploying it to heroku, it is throwing this error while consuming data via resttemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Forbidden because the server is not allowing your request. The APIs were restricted for non-Indian IP addresses. That is the most likely reason since your heroku deployment is perhaps outside of the Indian IP range.

Comment: Another reason could be that you are not authorized

Comment: Hi and welcome! Perhaps you can edit your response to make it more complete, instead of adding a comment to your response.